# LightSwitch Calendar Screen

Tags: html, visual-studio, calendar, lightswitch-2013

I'm looking for a HTML5 Visual Studio LightSwitch, calendar screen template or extension, similar to outlook or Google calendar. Or is there a way to implement Google's calendar efficiently and legally?

For example.

[image]
[image]

This preferably needs to be free, and used in multiple programs, being sold by my company. Seems simple, yet I've struggled finding anything similar online.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: agreed, i've hooked lightswitch HTML up to our outlook server so I can view/add calendar events to a shared calendar... but having an application in lightswitch would be a lot more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusions calendar is very good, and if it's for yourself only you can get a community licence, which gives you the control completely free. Im pretty sure its for small business's aswell that turn over less than $1,000,000 a year, might be worth dropping them an email and asking about it. The support also is excellent

Demo: http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/LightSwitch/HTMLClient/